# There exists $v_1,v_2\in A$ such that $v_1+v_2=1,v_1v_2=0$ and $v_i(x)=0$. Show that $A = A_1 \oplus A_2$ with $X_i= $ $^{a}\varphi(Spec(A_i))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $X_1,X_2$ are closed subsets of $Spec A$. There exists $v_1,v_2\in A$ such that $v_1+v_2=1,v_1v_2=0$ and $v_i(x)=0$ for all $x\in X_i,i=1,2$. Prove that there exist $A_1,A_2$ such that $A = A_1 \oplus A_2$ with $X_i= $ $^{a}\varphi(Spec(A_i)), \ i=1,2$.

What I think is that let $A_i=A/(u_i)$ and in this way we have $Spec(A/(u_i))=V(u_i)$ which is closed in $SpecA$. Since $A=(u_1)+(u_2)$, then we need to show that $(u_1)\cap(u_2)=\emptyset$ and then $A=A/(u_1)\oplus A/(u_2)$. But I don't know how to show $(u_1)\cap(u_2)=\emptyset$. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, you cannot show that the intersection of the ideals is the empty set, because $0$ is always in that intersection. See the linked duplicate for an explanation.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. So how can we show $A_1,A_2$ exist to make $A$ a direct sum of them?

Comment: $A_i=Av_i$.....

Comment: @KReiser Sorry I don't quite understand why in this way $v_i(x)=0$ for all $x\in$ $^a\varphi (Spec(A_i))$.

Comment: $v_2$ is sent to $0$ in $Av_1$ and vice versa.